# show hive partitions in a nested sub query

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a hive table that is partitioned by day (e.g. 20151001, 20151002,....).
Is there a hive query to list these partitions in a way that it is possible to be used in a nested sub query?

That is can I do something along the line of:

```
SELECT * FROM (SHOW PARTITIONS test) a where ...
```

The query-

```
SELECT ptn FROM test
```

returns as many rows as the number of rows in the test table. I want it to return only as many rows as the number of partitions (without using the DISTINCT function)

Answer (score 0):

A potential solution is to find the partitions from the hdfs location for the table of interest by using either shell script/python.

The data that corresponds to the hive table is stored in the hdfs e.g

/hive/database/table/partition/datafiles

in your case,
/hive/database/table/20151001/datafiles

If the table is bucketed there are as many individual files as the cluster size.

Once you have the above path, create a shell script to loop through the folder (in this case 20151001 etc..)

capture this in a shell variable and pass it as a parameter to the hive query.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11534953)

Comment: @il_raffa this provides an answer to the question, even so not using hive

Comment: @Virendhar Sivaraman Please improve your answer it is hardly understandable as it is currently written. To qualify as a good answer you should also describe in more detail how to perform the loop

Comment: added more details to the answer. hope this helps.